# Accessing module root path from spring cloud config server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have following modules in my project:

```
 root-mod
     + cloud-config-server
     + cloud-config-server-config-files
     + microservice-1
```

The directory `cloud-config-server-config-files` contain configuration files for the application and is a `git` repository. I would like to access these files from `application.yml` of `cloud-config-server` module. The problem here is that the following does not work: `${project.baseDir}/cloud-config-server-config-files/`. Is there a way to access the location from `application.yml` of my config server?

Answer (score 0):

Although not the most elegant solution(will keep this post open so that anyone with a better answer can answer), following worked for me:

> I created a property in the `pom.xml` of `cloud-config-server`:

```
<properties>
  <git-local-url>${project.basedir}/../cloud-config-server-config-files</git-local-url>
</properties>
```

> Then added the `resources` directory to the `<build>` tag:

```
<build>
   <resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           <filtering>true</filtering>
       </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
</build>
```

> Access this variable in `application.yml`:

```
uri: @git-local-url@
```

Ofcourse, this should be done based on the profiles there fore its best if the property is defied in the profile instead.

Cheers!